# Why doesn't Mathematica  expand Cos[x]^3 Sin[x]^2?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, trigonometry

I found some examples of Mathematica's commands usage in an old manual but the program gives me different result than expected

```
Expand[Cos[x]^3 Sin[x]^2, Trig -> True]
```

should give

```
Cos[x]/8 - Cos[3x]/16 - Cos[5x]/16
```

but returns an unaltered expression.

I tried out `Expand` with `Sin[x+y]` added to the expression, factored that and then I get what I expected in the first place. Why is that? I am surprised because I found that example in a book about Mathematica at my university's library. Although the book is from 1991 I don't think an unaltered expression is what `Expand` should return. Am I wrong?

Comment: What was the version of `Mathematica` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The function you want for this kind of case is [`TrigReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TrigReduce.html):

> `TrigReduce[expr]`
>   rewrites products and powers of trigonometric
>   functions in expr in terms of trigonometric functions with combined
>   arguments.

And it works:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

`Expand` doesn't work as you'd like even with `Trig -> True`. `TrigReduce` yields the experssion a bit different than expected. Instead, you can use [`Apart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apart.html?q=Apart&lang=en) with the option [`Trig`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Trig.html?q=Trig&lang=en) therein (by default `Options[Apart, Trig]` yields `{Trig -> False}`) to get exactly the expected output, e.g. :

```
Apart[ Cos[x]^3 Sin[x]^2, Trig -> True]
```

> ```
> Cos[x]/8 - 1/16 Cos[3 x] - 1/16 Cos[5 x]
> ```

exploiting your approach one could do this :

```
Unevaluated[ Expand[ Cos[x]^3 Sin[x]^2, Trig -> True]] /. Expand -> Apart
```

or

```
(Expand /. Expand -> Apart)[Cos[x]^3 Sin[x]^2, Trig -> True]
```

another ways use both `Apart` or `Expand` composed with `TrigToExp` and its "inverse" `ExpToTrig` :

```
ExpToTrig @ Apart @ TrigToExp[ Cos[x]^3 Sin[x]^2]
```

or

```
ExpToTrig @ Expand @ TrigToExp[ Cos[x]^3 Sin[x]^2]
```

**Edit**

Let's write all functions with the `Trig` option :

```
Select[ Names["*"], ( Length[ Quiet[ Options[ ToExpression @ #, Trig]]] == 1) &]
```

> ```
>  {"Apart", "ApartSquareFree", "Cancel", "Collect", "Denominator", "Expand",     
>   "ExpandAll", "ExpandDenominator", "ExpandNumerator", "Exponent", "Factor", 
>   "FactorList", "FactorSquareFree", "FactorSquareFreeList", "FactorTerms", 
>   "FactorTermsList", "FullSimplify", "Numerator", "PolynomialGCD",
>   "PolynomialLCM", "PolynomialMod", "Simplify", "Together"}
> ```

For their default settings :

```
{#, Quiet[ Options[ ToExpression @ #, Trig]]} & /@ %
```

Comment: Brilliant. I did not know `Apart` had that option, +1.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks !